# Trying to Clone one Element but multiplies items cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, append

I am trying to clone elements onclick one time only but multiple items are being cloned when I click continuously multiple times then multiple items created.

I don't understand why multiple items are created continuously. I only want items from the `data-id` should be appended one time even if I click it should be removed the cloned item. Also when we click appended items they should be removed.

```js
$('.item-save').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('productad')
  window.localStorage.setItem('test' + this.dataset.id, $(this).hasClass('productad'));
});

$('.item-save').each(function() {
  var id = 'test' + this.dataset.id;
  if (localStorage.getItem(id) && localStorage.getItem(id) == "true") {
    $(this).addClass('productad');
  }
});

$('.item-save').click(function() {
  var id = this.dataset.id;
  $(".item-save").attr("data-id", function() {
    var $button = $(this).clone();
    $button.appendTo('.item-append');
  });
});
```

```css
.item-save {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #a5a5a5;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='item-all'>
  <div class='item-save' data-id='123'>Save</div>
  <div class='item-save' data-id='124'>Save</div>
  <div class='item-save' data-id='125'>Save</div>
  <div class='item-save' data-id='126'></div>
</div>
<div class='item-append'></div>
```

Here is my code [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/sjb51fkc/1/)

I work with localStorage function to store some value so that is important without removing localStorage is it possible to fix this issue Any help or advice is highly appropriated

Comment: Why multiple items are created: you're using `$(".item-save").attr("data-id", function() {` which will loop through *all* of `.item-save` and clone each one, there's no need for this or to even change the `data-id` attribute.  `$(".item-save").click(function() { $(this).clone().appendTo...`

Comment: remove the loop part ... change to: `$(".item-save").click(function() { $(this).clone().appendTo...`

Comment: I am trying to clone elements onclick one time only but multiple items are being cloned when I click continuously multiple times then multiple items are created.  Please check jsFiddle Demo its Updated

Comment: So you now want to toggle the "item-appended" entry?   On the click, find a matching item in `.item-append` and remove it if it exists, otherwise add a new one.   You can match on attributes using `var existing = $(".item-append [data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]") if (existing.length > 0) existing.remove(); else ...clone...`

Comment: not works how setup this code provide any jsfiddle

Comment: please check my jsFiddle this code didn't work

Comment: Do you have an updated fiddle?  Looks good in https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/sjb51fkc/17  Just need to clone it when you first load at the time you read from localstorage (added to https://jsfiddle.net/bkf7ytoL/) then add the delegated event to remove when clicking on the item-append>.item-save from your other question.

Comment: Thanks very much for your efforts but the last issue is only remaining respected sir when I click on the appended element they didn't remove itself when we click on it?? is there any way to remove those appended elements when we click on them,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `attr()` function in your second click function.

Change this

```
$('.item-save').click(function() {
  var id = this.dataset.id;
  $(".item-save").attr("data-id", function() {
    var $button = $(this).clone();
    $button.appendTo('.item-append');
  });
});
```

To this

```
$('.item-save').click(function() {
     var $button = $(this).clone();
     $button.appendTo('.item-append');

});
```

Comment: I am trying to clone elements onclick one time only but multiple items are being cloned when I click continuously multiple times then multiple items are created. Please check jsFiddle Demo its Updated

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/yv3smx8p/1/ (sorry added the wrong link)

Comment: any solution dear sir